# I sent BUSD to a wallet as ERC20 when it was supposed to be sent as BEP20. How do I get it back. Owner of wallet says they can’t do anything. Help!

Tags: transactions, erc-20, wallet-transfer

How can I get my BUSD back or have proof that the wallet owner (defifarms “Alex Savil”)has my BUSD. Owner of the wallet states “they didn’t get it since it was sent on an eth block and not a Binance block there is nothing they can do. Is there someone or some company that I can contact to help retrieve my coin?

Here are specific details:

My trust wallet: 0x82F39FC8cE5Cdf5373F38e43aB01BECa3AB6F1aD

transferred BUSD erc20 To DeFiFarms wallet
0xe690a04740c7d92e92287c8700986335CDB0320f

Contract: 0x4fabb145d64652a948d72533023f6e7a623c7c53

Tx hash: 0xc031f9ad917fdcf600c2f4ac6c0213947428cb560fc4a7dc0769c51972173b6f

Then a few days later Defifarms wallet: 0xe690a04740c7d92e92287c8700986335CDB0320f

transferred MY money to here: 0x561f8ebdad2225cf4ca62ebc8e1339c4144244f1

Contract: 0x4Fabb145d64652a948d72533023f6E7A623C7C53

TX hash: 0x94aaeb5525b1fb2b2973822d7bef65ab45ded84c724e0a0b68cf66005edb061c

I have not followed the trail since but I was hoping someone would have suggestions or can help.

Comment: If I understand, you sent tokens to an address on the Ethereum blockchain instead of the Binance blockchain? and it happens that you have BUSD on both chains?

Comment: Thank you Kaki Master of TimeI believe the answer is yes  to your first question. I sent tokens to a wallet address  but used the wrong “type” I sent it as erc20  but was supposed to send it as BEP20. I think I was supposed to convert the BUSD to BEP 20 type but still learning. Can you rephrase 2nd question. BUSD on both chains?

Comment: ERC20 and BEP20 are very similar and I presume you are going to sell one to get the other via an exchange but with 1 to 1 price. my second question is not useful now. but you won't be able to get your tokens back from the wallet on the eth network. as the only way that you can transfer them back is that the new owner would do that and that's impossible.

Comment: By new owner you mean? So the owner of the wallet address is the same owner regardless of the block chain it was sent on? I just want to make sure I know for sure. BecUse I haven’t put anything on the telegram publicly and have been trying to get my money back politely but I continue to get the same answer “we didn’t receive it”

Comment: And yes it was a private sale for early investors before launch on pancakeswap. DefiFarms

Comment: No, the two chains are separate, the addresses exist on both chains but they are not controlled by the same entity. so your tokens are lost if you sent them to the address existing on the eth network instead of the bsc.